# Configure public domain for WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Any guidelines on how to configure public domain for WSO2 API Manager. Basically want to replace https://localhost:9043/publisher with http://api.test.com/publisher

We are using nginx. Our issue is how to correctly create the nginx conf.

Comment: You can refer http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2014/12/configure-wso2-api-manager-with-reverse.html

Answer (score 0):

Defined the server name as api.test.com in the virtual server block

```
server {

       listen 443;
       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
       server_name api.test.com;

    location /publisher {         
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/publisher;
           proxy_redirect  https://localhost:9443/publisher  https://localhost/apimanager/publisher;
           proxy_cookie_path /publisher /apimanager/publisher;

        }

       location ~ ^/publisher/(.*)registry/(.*)$ {         
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/$1registry/$2;
       }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I am still having problem with self signed ssl certificates. Test on a purchased ssl certificate and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. the above answers were useful. I got stuck because I did not have port 443 open (new to rackspace).